# getting IllegalStateException: closed while uploading image using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Couldn't get any response from the server, it shows IllegalStateException: closed, nothing else.

Also getting this in logcat: D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: activity to actvity#2

camera intent: calling the camera from here

```
private void cameraIntent() {
        if (network.isConnectedToInternet()) {

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, timeStamp);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
            imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        } else {
            Utilities.showMessageToUser(NetworkConstants.NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION, reachDeliveryLocationImageView, DeliveryRequestDetailsActivity.this);
        }
```

onActivityResult: getting the camera's response from here

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                try {
                    imageUrl = getRealPathFromUri(DeliveryRequestDetailsActivity.this, imageUri);
                    if (imageUrl != null) {
                        if (pickUpType.equalsIgnoreCase(TYPE_PICKUP)) {
                            String token = SharedPref.readString(SharedPref.TOKEN, null);
                            pickUpOrder(token, imageUrl, deliveryRequest.getSuborder().getId(), String.valueOf(myLocation.getLatLng().latitude), String.valueOf(myLocation.getLatLng().longitude), deliveryRequest.getId());
                        } else if (pickUpType.equalsIgnoreCase(TYPE_DELIVER)) {
                            String token = SharedPref.readString(SharedPref.TOKEN, null);
                            showBottomDialogForOTP(token, imageUrl, deliveryRequest.getSuborder().getId());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, NetworkConstants.CAMERA_WAIT_TIME);
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

api call: making api call from here

```
private void pickUpOrder(final String token, final String filePath, final String subOrderId, final String latitude, final String longitude, final String requestID) {
        showProgressDialog();

        File file = new File(filePath);
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(NetworkConstants.IMAGE, file.getName(), requestFile);
        MultipartBody.Part subOrderPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(NetworkConstants.SUB_ORDER, subOrderId);
        MultipartBody.Part latitudePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(NetworkConstants.LATITUDE, latitude);
        MultipartBody.Part longitudePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(NetworkConstants.LONGITUDE, longitude);
        MultipartBody.Part deliveryRequestPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(NetworkConstants.DELIVERY_REQUEST, requestID);

        if (mAPIService == null) {
            mAPIService = ApiClient.getClient(this).create(ApiInterface.class);
        }

        mAPIService.pickUpOrder(subOrderPart, latitudePart, longitudePart, part, deliveryRequestPart, "Bearer " + token).enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<JsonElement> call, @NonNull Response<JsonElement> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                      "not getting any response"
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<JsonElement> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "pickup: under on failure");
            }
        });
    }
```

api interface method:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("img/")
    Call<JsonElement> pickUpOrder(@Part MultipartBody.Part subOrder,
                                  @Part MultipartBody.Part latitude,
                                  @Part MultipartBody.Part longitude,
                                  @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                  @Part MultipartBody.Part deliveryRequest,
                                  @Header("Authorization") String token);
```

Comment: can you post some code of what you are doing?

Comment: Can not understand anything from the above information. Please add some code snippet in the question

Comment: @BasavarajHadimani thnx for your quick reply I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the image size. Compressing the image does the job

Using this https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor library will solve the problem